# What type of sealants are used to seal vacuum chambers?

Tags: vacuum, seals

I'm building a vacuum chamber and I want to seal it
It's a 200mm^3 acrylic box

What type of sealant should I use?
For the door I guess it has to be something else then the walls because it need to be reopen?

*The acrylic is going to be THICC

Comment: I tend to favor automotive RTV.  seals great and can be used to make gaskets too.  toggle clamps provide pressure to seal a door.

Comment: What specification of vacuum? If it's acrylic, guessing not too tight, but a lot of vacuum work is about preventing any materials that outgas . . .   For the door, static face seals with Viton o-ring material is a typical starting point if you have nothing else to go on. They make "vacuum grease" especially for this o-ring application.

Comment: With a "good" vacuum , I would suspect the acrylic could distort and permit leaks at closures.

Comment: 200 mm³ would be a cube with 5.84 mm sides. Do you mean a 200 mm cube? Tip: use `<sup>3</sup>` HTML markup for superscript.